# What is the hook after item is added to cart in Drupal Ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I have been trying to get a hook that executes just after item is added to a cart.
I knw there is a hook called hook_uc_add_to_cart that runs when item is added to cart.But i want to show a form and do the proecessing of form after item is added to cart.
The problem is while i try to do form processing using drupal_goto in the hook,it does not return anything as per the hook requirements.Hence after my form is processed,the item is not added to cart.
Therefore i am looking for a hook that runs after item is successfully added to cart.Any help or pointers to it.
Many Thanks 
Smith

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the hook for successful payment in ubercart 3.x for drupal 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675711/what-is-the-hook-for-successful-payment-in-ubercart-3-x-for-drupal-7)

Comment: Next time, make sure you specify your Drupal and Ubercart version :)

Comment: Definitely Ayesh..It is drupal 7 with ubercart 3.x.

Comment: So far i am not able to find any hook.However i wanted to redirect the user to other page.And i came to know that in admin panel we can set the path where the page redirects after an item is added to cart.We have to go to admin panel.Then go to store->configuration->cart. Here we will find the place to set the path...hope it helps somebody...